# Yii 1.1.16, how to detect action, what is runned from code?

Tags: php, oop, yii

i have small trouble...

```
class Controller {
      init() {
        // initializing...

        // render header && footer
        $header = (new HeaderAction)->run();
        $footer = (new FooterAction)->run();

        // redirect to called action, what renders all the content
      }
    }
```

What i can detect diff between ->run() and called action?

Comment: I want to create class MyAction, what can returns RenderPartial content, and can return Render content as a different ways

Answer (score 0):

Answer found in:
AfterRender -> parse Route -> compare action names. If match - echo, if not match - Return.

Yii is SHIT!!!
I will write new class MyAction with method AddData, what can render for me some viewfile. Creating class CAction for this, what can't rendering? Maybe i must create controller? Are you noob, Quang, ha?

Lol, i can't create the header with action. I must create it in Controller. Controller file now is 1200 lines. >_<

```
class MyAction {
 public $data = array();
 public function addData($name, $val) {
   $this->data[$name] = $val;
 }
 public function render($file) {
   ob_start;
   // ... something
   return ob_get_clean;
 };
}
```

/// ITS ALL WHAT NEED ALL THE DEVELOPERS>>>>
BEHAVIORS? EVENTS? FILTERS? WIDGETS? MODULES? MAYBE WE NEED "CAMOBAP" AS AUTOCAR?
REASOOOONS????

===

Lol, there is model cannot to render at all. I have products with views as "tr-tr", and i must create controller, create action, create route for rendering funcking 10 SYMBOLS.... Its Rage. About u, Quang.

Russian Bear will kill you.